# android game pause screen , dialog or activity dialog?

Tags: android, menu, dialog

I am a little confused about the best way to show pause screen on my android game. will it be better to be a pauseMenuActivity or is it enough with just pauseDialog? this pause dialog will just show score, money, back button, option button , and quit button. if it is better to show dialog, I don't know how to show those buttons and background image.. anyone can help me? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend going for a Dialog (or some other custom overlay). From my experience, inter-Activities transitions aren't always very quick and they can feel kind of sluggish in the context of a game. In my opinion, when I am on a pause screen and want to start playing again, it should be instantaneous.

Plus, an Activity is kind of overkill if you just want to show 4 buttons.

To create a custom dialog containing a custom layout, have a look at the following tutorial and post again if you have specific questions/problems :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: that's right, activity calling is kind of long process. :) , but custom dialog like that one will result different depend on the phone theme. I want to create custom pause menu like in those popular game like Angry Birds, but i don't know how to make it. any idea?

Comment: Well, what I did for my game is that I have one activity. The various game screens are just views (inherit from the View class). I add all these game screens to a ViewAnimator and use ViewAnimator.setDisplayChild to switch between the currently displayed view. I think the only drawback is that all the views will be kept in-memory but if it's only for a 4-buttons pause menu, it won't eat all your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

An Activity in general is better than a dialog, because u can take care of all things like orientation, theme etc. and it provides more flexibility. Though in simple cases u can use a dialog.

Comment: the question is, will the game activity reset or not after i go back to the game?

Comment: You have to add the proper processing to actually "pause" and "resume" the gameplay.