# Android game dev: switching between views

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

I am working on creating a simple game using Android and I have this question on best practices for how to transition between a couple of the game screens.

The game screens are very simple in my game (like MainGameScreen, PauseScreen, SettingsScreen, etc.) with just a couple of buttons and some text. So I am thinking to put everything in one activity, create a separate view for each of the screens and then have something to transition between these views.

I was thinking of using ViewAnimator to switch between the screens (see here [android game pause screen , dialog or activity dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290333/android-game-pause-screen-dialog-or-activity-dialog/5290375)), but I have the problem of ViewAnimator only lets me switch based on an index (ie. I can't switch to my desired view using a layout id). So I think maybe ViewAnimator is not the best class for the job.

Is there another class that is more suitable for switching between views of my choice?

Thankyou everybody for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you looking for is a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) , you can also store the id of the pages and then navigate through them